# How to divide all items in one list using all items in another list, and doing all possible combinations?

Tags: python, list

I'm having a bit of a problem here. For example, there are 2 lists:

```
a=[12,3,4,6,2]
b=[6,2,1,3,12]
```

What I want to do is make a new list which consists of:

```
c=[2,6,12,4,1,0.5, ...]
```

Also, is there any way to do this without importing anything?

Comment: how you want to create new list? do you want to mix them ?

Comment: Where does the `0.5` come from?

Comment: I meant more like:
    c=[12/6, 12/2, 12/1, ...]

Comment: 0.5 comes from "3/6"

Answer (score 2):

Using set comprehension (to prevent duplicated items):

```
>>> a = [12,3,4,6,2]
>>> b = [6,2,1,3,12]
>>> c = {x/y for x in a for y in b}  # float(x)/y  in Python 2.x
>>> c
{0.5, 1.0, 2.0, 1.5, 4.0, 3.0, 6.0, 0.25, 0.6666666666666666, 1.3333333333333333, 
 0.16666666666666666, 12.0, 0.3333333333333333}
```

Use [`list`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-list) to get a list object instead of a [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-set):

```
>>> list(c)
[0.5, 1.0, 2.0, 1.5, 4.0, 3.0, 6.0, 0.25, 0.6666666666666666, 1.3333333333333333,
 0.16666666666666666, 12.0, 0.3333333333333333]
```

Comment: +1 not sure why I should complicate things sometimes

Answer (score 1):

You could use list comprehensions:

> ```
> [float(x)/y for x in a for y in b]
> [2.0, 6.0, 12.0, 4.0, 1.0, 0.5, 1.5, 3.0, 1.0, 0.25, 0.6666666666666666, 2.0, 4.0, 1.3333333333333333, 0.3333333333333333, 1.0, 3.0, 6.0, 2.0, 0.5, 0.3333333333333333, 1.0, 2.0, 0.6666666666666666, 0.16666666666666666]
> ```

If you want the result in fractions you should import the fractions module:

> ```
> import fractions
> set([fractions.Fraction(x)/y for x in a for y in b])
> set([Fraction(1, 2), Fraction(1, 1), Fraction(2, 1), Fraction(3, 1), Fraction(4, 1), Fraction(6, 1), Fraction(12, 1), Fraction(1, 3), Fraction(2, 3), Fraction(4, 3), Fraction(1, 6), Fraction(1, 4), Fraction(3, 2)])
> ```

Comment: Great! This is what I was looking for. On a side note, how do you make it so that a character in "c" does not repeat?For example, I only want 2.0 to appear once.

EDIT: NVM! I got it

Comment: Use set: set([float(x)/y for x in a for y in b])

Answer (score 0):

You can use `itertools.product` to get all the pairs to substract:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> pairs = list(itertools.product(*(a,b)))
>>> pairs
[(12, 6), (12, 2), (12, 1), (12, 3), (12, 12), (3, 6), (3, 2), (3, 1), (3, 3), (3, 12), (4, 6), (4, 2), (4, 1), (4, 3), (4, 12), (6, 6), (6, 2), (6, 1), (6, 3), (6, 12), (2, 6), (2, 2), (2, 1), (2, 3), (2, 12)]
```

Then you divide:

```
>>> [a/b for a,b in pairs]
[2, 6, 12, 4, 1, 0, 1, 3, 1, 0, 0, 2, 4, 1, 0, 1, 3, 6, 2, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0]
>>>
```

If you want floats:

```
>>> [float(a)/b for a,b in pairs]
[2.0, 6.0, 12.0, 4.0, 1.0, 0.5, 1.5, 3.0, 1.0, 0.25, 0.6666666666666666, 2.0, 4.0, 1.3333333333333333, 0.3333333333333333, 1.0, 3.0, 6.0, 2.0, 0.5, 0.3333333333333333, 1.0, 2.0, 0.6666666666666666, 0.16666666666666666]
```

Putting all together in a one-liner:

```
>>> [float(a)/b for a,b in it.product(*(a,b))]
```